# Properties of expectation values of quantum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

$$\langle \hat A \rangle \langle \hat B \rangle=\langle \hat A\hat B \rangle,$$

$$\langle \hat A \rangle + \langle \hat B \rangle=\langle \hat A + \hat B \rangle,$$

$$\langle \hat A^2 \rangle \langle \hat B^2 \rangle=\langle \hat A^2 \hat B^2 \rangle,$$

$$\langle \hat A^2 \rangle +  \langle \hat B^2 \rangle=\langle \hat A^2 + \hat B^2 \rangle,$$
Which one of them is not true!?

Comment: Please see the [FAQ on what kinds of questions to ask](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) and [meta on how one can ask basic questions without running afoul of those restrictions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 1):

The second and the fourth formula are true if $\langle\dots \rangle$ is linear. So most likely, these statements are true in your context.

---

For the other two, consider $\hat B:=\hat A$ and notice that $\langle \hat A \rangle^2 =\langle \hat A^2 \rangle$ is not true (there is a thread about this somewhere).

Or consider $\hat B:=\hat A^{-1}$, then $\hat A\hat B$ becomes the unity on the right hand side, but you still have something to calculate on the left hand side. E.g. take a $2$x$2$ diagonal matrix with one big and one small entry in a state $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$ and see that the left hand side is not $1$ but will depend on the matrix entries.